# Automatically run maven on save in MyEclipse, without committing project files

Tags: css, eclipse, maven, less, myeclipse

This may be a problem that others have had before, but I've not been able to find the right search terms if so.

I am using LESS CSS (a CSS pre-processor) in my webapp, and I need it automatically compile a CSS file whenever a LESS file is saved, such that I can just refresh my browser and see the changes. I have previously been successful in doing this by changing the project properties in MyEclipse, in order to point at an external maven executable, and the generate-sources phase within my project's POM.

We're now in the progress of transitioning to GIT (very slowly), and as a step on that path, we want to ensure none of the project files are in version control. Obviously this means that setting up an external executable in the project files is no longer viable, if I want all developers to automatically have this happen for them.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction for solving my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the web resource optimizer for java (aka [wro4j](http://code.google.com/p/wro4j/)). It can apply less css processor (or many other [processors](http://code.google.com/p/wro4j/wiki/AvailableProcessors)) using both: runtime solution (as a [filter](http://alexo.github.com/wro4j/)) or build-time solution (as a [maven plugin](http://code.google.com/p/wro4j/wiki/MavenPlugin) with [m2-wro4j eclipse plugin](https://github.com/jbosstools/m2e-wro4j) which is capable of identifying incremental builds).

Alternatively, there is a lightweight solution which process the less resources on the fly, using the [LessCssFilter](http://code.google.com/p/wro4j/wiki/AbstractProcessorsFilter)

Comment: Thanks .... good answer. I'll do some investigation into those suggestions and see if any of them work for me.

Comment: Ended up using the underlying LESS processor from wro4j (although the name escapes me temporarily) in a Java filter, and am parsing on initial request and then caching for the life of the application (i.e. until JVM restart). We then have a config file on only the developers machines that - on server start - is read and will turn on a "parse on every request" flag if required. LESS responses for cached files are under 1ms, so well within production requirements. Thanks for the advice and pointers ... very helpful.

Comment: Could you share your approach? It would be interesting to see a demo or quick start project using it..